# Unable to see rendered View even after adding HDRI and exr files

Tags: hdri

I am adding hdri and exr files to Env texture but even then i am unable to see the view ( in rendered mode) .
It was wroking last week with some files ,but now its not working.
Attached is screenshot.
[image]
Please help.

Comment: you have a seconed world output somewere. you can see that because the one in your image is grey and not red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the *World Output* node doesn't have a red header and the *World Properties* show that a background node is connected, you have another *World Output* that is active. You will have to remove the duplicate output in the node editor, that is likely somewhere outside the visible area. All nodes can be brought into the view through *View > View All* (<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>pos1</kbd>).

The proper node setup for HDRIs is shown in the following image:

[image: World nodes]

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert.